# Is it possible to split react packages from vendors bundle and run application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-5

i try to optimize vendors bundle produced by webpack to multiple custom chunks. The problem is, after the build and creating chunks, my react application doesn't load. I tried different order of scripts also... If i run app with vendors and main bundle it works well.

tsconfig

```
{
    "version": "3.2",
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2015",
        "jsx": "react",
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
}
```

webpack.config

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: ['@babel/polyfill', './App/myapp.tsx']
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: __dirname + "/appscripts"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|tsx|ts)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-typescript',
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            '@babel/preset-react'
                        ],
                        plugins: [
                            [
                                "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator", { "asyncGenerators": false, "generators": false, "async": false }
                            ],
                            [
                                "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
            minSize: 0,
            cacheGroups: {
                reactVendor: {
                    test: /([\\/]node_modules[\\/](react|react-dom)[\\/])/,
                    name: "react~bundle"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

In my html i put scripts in src tag like vendors~bundle, react~bundle, bundle.

I tried several plugins, read dozens of articles... Babel, support for IE 11 is needed.

Is it even possible to do split like this ?